# When rendering Rmarkdown from another script, tables not appearing

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

When I use the knit button in Rstudio the .RMD file renders perfectly into a HTML and all my tables appear.

My r script that automates my reports looks like the following

```
source("users/some_name/some_file/get_some_data.R")

render("users/some_name/some_file/foo.Rmd") 

source("users/some_name/some_file/email_data_report.R")
```

When run the above r script the tables do not appear in the HTML file produced.

Even when I tried the various table producing packages (base,KableExtra,reactable,DT, etc)

If I run the following in my foo.Rmd file -

```
datatable(iris)
```

I get a table underneath the code chunk in the Rstudio viewer and it appears when I use the knit button but as mentioned not when I call `render` for another r script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the `child` chunk option instead of `render()`, e.g.

````
```{r table, child = 'users/some_name/some_file/foo.Rmd'}

```
````

Another example, this is how I picuture the RMD-file where `df` is created by the data r-file:

````
```{r}
source("data.R")
```


```{r table}
DT::datatable(df)
```
````

Comment: What happens if you source the R-data file inside your rmd-file?

Comment: I added ```knitr::read_chunk('get_data.R') ``` then called ```<<get_data>>``` to run the script in the Rmd file.  When I ```render()```. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Try it to put the source code like this in the rmd-fike: `
`  ```{r}
 source('get_some_data.R.R')
 ``` ` 
and then compile it

Comment: Also no good, the rest of the graphics - ggplots etc will appear but the tables do not.  I tried a simple example putting a ```datatable(iris)``` in the Rmarkdown template then ```render('Rmarkdown_template.Rmd)``` It reproduces the problem.

Comment: That's weird, my MWE works for me as expected..

Comment: R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0 
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status  
major          4  
minor          1.1                         
year           2021                        
month          08                          
day            10                          
svn rev        80725                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
nickname       Kick Things